# PHP SQL Return the field with highest count

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I need a query which returns the site which contains the highest count.

See a sample table below:

fields:

```
id | site

1  | site1
2  | site2
3  | site3
4  | site3
```

In this case above it should return site3.

How can I do this?

Comment: select count(*) as total from table group by site order by total desc limit 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/42b92/6/0)):

```
SELECT TOP 1 site
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY site
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

OR MySQL ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77cb4/4/0)):

```
SELECT site 
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY site
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select site, count(id) from table group by site order by count(id) desc limit 1
```

Should work

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT site, 
         COUNT(site) TotalCount
    FROM table_name
GROUP BY site
  ORDER BY count(id) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This would return any site with a count of 2 or greater.  In the case of the sample data it would return `site3`.  But if there are several `site`s with more than one entry it would return them all.

Answer (score 0):

if you want field **site** as result here's the query:

`SELECT COUNT(site), site FROM tab GROUP BY site DESC LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 0):

This one should work

```
select max(C), S from (select count(id) C ,site S from table group by site) tab
```

Answer (score 0):

simple `count` and `group` your query and `order by` the count column

```
SELECT 
      COUNT(id) as amount, 
      site 
FROM sitetable 

GROUP BY site 
ORDER BY amount DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score -1):

SELECT MAX(`id`) AS id, `site` FROM `demo`

It's return
id site
4  site3

Comment: ``max`` function only return the max value from the current column

Comment: you want max id and max id site name or value right?

Comment: i'm not the guy who asked, but i think you misunderstood the question. he wants the ``site`` with the highest occur amount in the table